# Will changing my Geometry Dash username affect my levels?

Tags: geometry-dash

I would like to change my Geometry Dash username. I know how, but will all my posted levels still have my old name and will changing the username negatively affect them?

I have changed my name and waited, but it still lists me as my old name when commenting, and viewing my name on levels. The only place it shows my updated name is when you are actually on my profile. Is there a way to get it to display my new name and not my old name?

Answer (score 2):

It will not change your levels, It takes a while for the levels to change to your new name, but It will change the creator name

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the name offline then this means old level scores will still be on the old name, if you need to be online to do it it should update your levels with the new name

Answer (score 0):

It will have no effect on any of your levels (apart from your online levels, which when people will see them, will say by: new username rather than by: old username)